# How shift few row values in a dataframe to the previous row by retaining other values?

Tags: r

I used `distinct` on a variable and `group_by` on a different variable. Now, I have rows that are replicated since I used `group_by` and `distinct` together. Now I need to move few column values to the previous row and delete the row which is duplicated. Take a look at the example given.

I tried another `distinct` on the `Fixation` column. But it does not retain the 4th and 6th column value!

```
155 B01 C21 NA          154 NA  Fixation    366 
156 B01 C21 1   B       154 NA  Fixation    366
210 B02 C21     NA      53  NA  Fixation    566
211 B02 C21 1   NumPad6 53  NA  NA          NA
```

Expected output

```
155 B01 C21 1       B   154 NA  Fixation    366
210 B02 C21 1   NumPad6 53  NA  Fixation    566
```

```
156 B01 C21 1   B   154 - delete this row from the df--
211 B02 C21 1   NumPad6 53  - delete this row from the df--
```

Comment: I just noticed your rows are not of equal lengths - there's something missing in column 5 in row 1 and column 4 in row 3. What should be there?

Comment: They are just empty cells. I am going add NA values to the empty cells.

Comment: yeah, that's what I did. So my solution below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% select(-V1,-V7) %>% #V7 is all NAs, so I need to remove it. V1 is the row-number
  group_by(V2,V3) %>% 
  summarize_all(~unique(.[!is.na(.)]))

# A tibble: 2 x 7
# Groups:   V2 [2]
  V2    V3       V4 V5          V6 V8          V9
  <chr> <chr> <int> <chr>    <int> <chr>    <int>
1 B01   C21       1 B          154 Fixation   366
2 B02   C21       1 NumPad64    53 Fixation   566
```

(note that I replaced the missing values from your original table with NAs)

Comment: I used `lead` in the `dplyr` pipes. It moved the column by one row and allowed me to use `distinct` later on. However, your solution gave me a good idea.